# How to install cogen python coroutine framework on Mac OS X

Tags: python

I did

```
sudo easy_install cogen
```

and got :

```
Searching for cogen
Best match: cogen 0.2.1
Processing cogen-0.2.1-py2.5.egg
cogen 0.2.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/cogen-0.2.1-py2.5.egg
Processing dependencies for cogen
Searching for py-kqueue>=2.0
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/py-kqueue/
Best match: py-kqueue 2.0.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/py-kqueue/py-kqueue-2.0.1.zip#md5=98d0c0d76c1ff827b3de33ac0073d2e7
Processing py-kqueue-2.0.1.zip
Running py-kqueue-2.0.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-M8cj_5/py-kqueue-2.0.1/egg-dist-tmp-lDR6ry
kqueuemodule.c: In function ‘kqueue_new_kevent’:
kqueuemodule.c:71: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
kqueuemodule.c: In function ‘kqueue_keventType_setattr’:
kqueuemodule.c:217: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
kqueuemodule.c: In function ‘kqueue_new_kevent’:
kqueuemodule.c:71: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
kqueuemodule.c: In function ‘kqueue_keventType_setattr’:
kqueuemodule.c:217: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
No eggs found in /tmp/easy_install-M8cj_5/py-kqueue-2.0.1/egg-dist-tmp-lDR6ry (setup script problem?)
error: Could not find required distribution py-kqueue>=2.0
```

Would appreciate any pointers on how to get the dependencies installed on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be some problem with setuptools -- the dependencies are compiled succesfully but not installed. FWIW it works for me (OSX 10.5.6, MacPython 2.5).

I would try reinstalling setuptools, and if that fails downloading and "`python setup.py install`"ing cogen and py-kqueue manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading 'pip' (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) and use that instead of easy_install. It just worked for me.